# WordPress TEMPLATEPATH

Tags: wordpress

Where in WordPress is TEMPLATEPATH initially set?

Comment: You define it in `wp-settings.php`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It points to the template of your wordpress that is active.

```
<?php echo TEMPLATEPATH; ?>
```

This will give you the actual path.

Incase you are using a child theme, then this points to the childtheme. This is really handy because...

```
bloginfo('template_url')
```

This doesn't point to the child theme and creates problem for new developers using child theme.

Answer (score 12):

TEMPLATEPATH has been **deprecated**.

Use the following to include files:

```
 // Load entire ThemeSmith framework
 include get_template_directory() . '/my-extra-functions.php';
```

Comment: get_stylesheet_directory() will return a child theme's directory whereas get_template_directory() will always return a parent's theme directory http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory  Notes on deprecation http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18298